# Downloading pictures using BS4

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For some reason this following section of my function doesn't append any links to the list 'links'

```
links = []    #this is defined globally outside of the current function
k = 0

def scrape_site(url): 
    sources = soup.find_all('img')

    for link in sources:
        image_links = link.get('src')
        if '.jpg' in image_links:
            for i in image_links.split("\\n"):
                links.append(i.split())

    while k <= (len(links) - 1):
        img_name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
        fullName = str(img_name) + ".jpg"
        lines = links[k][0]
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(lines, fullName)
        print(lines)
        print(fullName + '\n')
```

Here's the page that I have the soup object for:

https://www.willhaben.at/iad/kaufen-und-verkaufen/d/rwc-luxus-herrenfahrrad-428141412/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download the images, try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.willhaben.at/iad/kaufen-und-verkaufen/d/rwc-luxus-herrenfahrrad-428141412/").content

images = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").find("div", class_="galleria on").find_all("img")

for image in images:
    image_src_url = image["src"]
    print(f"Fetching {image_src_url}...")
    with open(image_src_url.split("/")[-1], "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(image_src_url).content)
```

Output:

```
Fetching https://cache.willhaben.at/mmo/2/428/141/412_1805375677.jpg...
Fetching https://cache.willhaben.at/mmo/2/428/141/412_1462293254.jpg...
Fetching https://cache.willhaben.at/mmo/2/428/141/412_1537001347.jpg...
```

And check your local folder for image files.

Comment: Thank you! I got it working using my variable names. How do I change the location of the pictures and is there anyway to rename these pictures using the index of a related pandas dataframe? This may be out of the scope of this question

Comment: Sorry, still relatively new to this platform

Comment: As for your further questions, what do you mean by changing the location of the pictures? Saving them to a different folder locally? And sure, you can rename the files based on a pd Dataframe, but it'd be best to ask a separate question.

Comment: Yes, saving them to a different folder locally. I'll be downloading quite a lot of images by turning this into a loop and want them saved in a separate folder named with their respective pd dataframe index. I'll ask the df index question once I have all my other ducks in a row